# How to copy assets with vue-cli-service build command?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-cli

Below is the content of my app `src` directory. How can I copy files located in `src/assets/others` to `dist/others` folder with `vue-cli-service build` command? Btw. my project was created with `vue create` command.

```
    src/
    ├── App.vue
    ├── assets
    |    ├── others
    |        └── metadata.xlsx
    dist/
    ├── css
    │   ├── app.4d032e62.css
    │   └── chunk-vendors.f6f30965.css
    ├── favicon.ico
    ├── img
    │   └── upload.a0fd70ac.svg
    ├── index.html
    └── js
        ├── app.11cd5b00.js
        ├── app.11cd5b00.js.map
        ├── chunk-vendors.58c6929b.js
        └── chunk-vendors.58c6929b.js.map
```

Answer (score 10):

In a Vue CLI project, the `src/assets` directory normally contains files that are processed by Webpack (for minification, etc.), and [static assets](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html#static-assets-handling) are stored in the `public` directory. So, you could move your `src/assets/others` to `public/others`, where they'll automatically be copied to `dist` during the build.

On the other hand, if you'd rather the `src/assets` directory also contain static assets for some reason, you could [configure the `WebpackCopyPlugin`](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/copy-webpack-plugin#patterns) (already included in Vue CLI) to copy `src/assets/others` to `dist/others` at build time:

```js
// vue.config.js
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
  chainWebpack: config => {
    config.plugin('copy')
          .tap(args => {
            args[0].push({
              from: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/assets/others'),
              to: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist/others'),
              toType: 'dir',
              ignore: ['.DS_Store']
            })
            return args
          })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With webpack 5 and vue-cli 5 this changed to:

```js
// vue.config.js
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
  chainWebpack: (config) => {
    config.plugin('copy').tap((entries) => {
      entries[0].patterns.push({
        from: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/assets/others'),
        to: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist/others'),
        toType: 'dir',
        noErrorOnMissing: true,
        globOptions: { ignore: ['.DS_Store'] },
      })

      return entries
    })
  },
}
```

Comment: I changed my ` vue.config.js` to yours and nothing happens. I am trying to copy `dist` frolder to `dist2`

Comment: I think you need `devServer: { writeToDisk: true }` when in dev mode.